# pylint R1720: Unnecessary "elif" after "raise" (no-else-raise)

Tags: python, pylint

I have the following code

```
    if self.download_format == 'mp3':
        raise NotImplementedError
    elif self.download_format == 'wav':
        with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.wav') as wavfile:
            self.download_wav_recording(call, wavfile.name)
            convert_wav_to_mp3(wavfile.name, filename)
```

And pylint reports this error

```
R1720: Unnecessary "elif" after "raise" (no-else-raise)
```

What is the motivation for this error? why this code is not ok?

Comment: The `else` part of `elif` is redundant in this case, because the `raise` will exit the block.

Comment: I would still keep this code as is, much clearer to read as `if-elif` than 2 `if`s

Comment: What unclear is in two subsequent `if`s?

Comment: Two `if`s implies that both could be true; `if-elif` more strongly suggests that only one code path can be taken.

Comment: IMO, `pylint` is being overly opinionated here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
    if self.download_format == 'mp3':
        raise NotImplementedError
    elif self.download_format == 'wav':
        with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.wav') as wavfile:
            self.download_wav_recording(call, wavfile.name)
            convert_wav_to_mp3(wavfile.name, filename)
```

This is equivalent to

```
    if self.download_format == 'mp3':
        raise NotImplementedError
    if self.download_format == 'wav':
      with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.wav') as wavfile:
          self.download_wav_recording(call, wavfile.name)
          convert_wav_to_mp3(wavfile.name, filename)
```

Hence the warning from pylint

The `raise` causes control flow to be disrupted - so you don't need to use `elif` and can use `if` instead

Comment: I am not understanding it, if the first statement holds it will check the next elif

Comment: @bonijad383, if the first `if` statement holds true, an exception is raised and not caught, and hence, the surrounding block of the `if-elif` control flow is exited. As such, `pylint` suggests that the `else` part of `elif` that follows the exception raising logic is redundant. The only possible branch to hit the comparison `self.download_format == 'wav'` is only via the `else`, anyway.